# Meck and Test Driven Development workflow?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, erlang, mocking, tdd

As to my knowledge, the typical workflow (W1) of TDD is as follows:

1. Develop a test for a function;
2. Run the test and watch it failing;
3. Develop the function;
4. Run the test again and watch it passing;
5. Repeat 1.

But with Meck and other mocking frameworks, the workflow (W2) could be the following:

1. Write tests for all functions and watch them failing;
2. Develop a complete system prototype (all functions and their interaction) with the help of mock objects;
3. Run the tests again and watch them passing;
4. Gradually change each mock function to a real one, step-by-step.

I tend to think that W2 has some advantages over W1:

- faster to write;
- easier integration, since all tests (both unit and integration tests) will be written in advance; also they they will pass from the very beginning;

So, the question is:

Does W2 really have the advantages described above? If no, how can I incorporate Meck into my daily development as an established routine, i.e. what would be a workflow of using it? Or should I just use Meck randomly without any guidance?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use mocks exclusivly to make the tests pass. If that would be possible, either your tests are not worth their name or you wouldn't need to replace the mocks with "real" code as the mocks already do what you want the code to do.

Mocks are usually used to isolate the system under test (SUT), i.e. the class you want to test, from its dependencies. The dependencies are mocked, the SUT is not.

Answer (score 1):

W2 assumes that you have completed a correct design for the system before you start -- a position I, for one, am rarely in.  You would have to do big design up front; IME that means that you've moved the expensive part of the development process rather than eliminating it.  And if your initial design happens to be flawed (and it will be), recovering will be expensive.

Tests that pass from the beginning, by the by, are a bug, not a feature.  Writing specifically failing tests is a crucial step -- how else will you demonstrate that the code you wrote actually works?

I can't speak to Meck specifically, but I can speak to the general TDD workflow, which incorporates the various flavors of mock objects naturally.  Mock objects exist to let unit tests pass regardless of whether the rest of the system works.  They also provide natural signposts for what you'll need to do next.  In order to make unit test A pass, you had to mock a class B.  Clearly, the next thing to do is to implement a class B that behaves the way its mock up describes it.

Your W1 leaves out a few crucial steps, the inclusion of which might clarify the role mock objects play in TDD.  Illustrated as pseudo-Perl, the TDD looks more like this:

```
while (not $project->is_feature_complete()) {
  my $feature_test = write_feature_test();
  die "You screwed up" if $feature_test->does_pass();
  $feature_test_suite->add($feature_test);
  while (not $feature_test_suite->does_pass()) {
    my $test = write_unit_test();
    die "You screwed up" if $test->does_pass();
    $unit_test_suite->add($test);
    while (not $unit_test_suite->does_pass()) {
      write_exactly_enough_code_to_pass_unit_test();
      while ($project->has_duplication()) {
        $project->eliminate_duplication();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The key differences from your W1 are:

- Surrounding the cycle of unit tests is another cycle of feature test.
- The feature test might be kept failing for a while; it can't pass until the integration of all its dependencies is complete.
- We are extremely parsimonious with the code we write to pass the unit test.  And since mock objects are easier to write than real working classes, it is implied that we mock out every dependency we discover while trying to do so.
- Elimination of duplication is crucially necessary, and is the step where we often replace mock objects with real implementations.

That last point might need more amplification (preferably without repeating the *entirety* of *Test-Driven Development by Example*[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-Driven_Development_by_Example)).  What happens is that the shortest way to make the second test pass is often to use a copy of the mock object that made the first test pass with some parameters tweaked.  During the "eliminate duplication" step, we combine these two mock objects into a single parameterized one.  Once we've repeated that cycle a few times, the mock object we've constructed is very nearly identical to the real object we need, and so we can use the its code to start implementing the dependency it has thus far hidden.

In all of this, the role of mock objects is pretty much always the same:  Allowing you to make unit tests pass without having to implement the entire system at once.  Using them to implement the entire system up front seems to me to waste most of their utility while also exposing you to the usual risks of big up-front design.  I do not think you get the benefits you think you will; at best, you change the accounting such that time spent "coding" is reduced.